# Retrieving data from form made in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have uploaded a fiddle of my JS code (http://jsfiddle.net/3mcm2/), at the very bottom of which is the way in which I am calling the JS in my PHP document.  In order to run the script, just remove the PHP code comments from the bottom.  I just wanted to add that for you to see how I am outputting it in PHP.  Also, above those last comments are three lines of comments in the .js file, which are there for you to see what it is that the PHP is echoing just to help you better understand how everything looks.

```
/* The following is what is in my .js file: (see the bottom of this script for part of         
   what is in my PHP file) */

var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method', "get");
f.setAttribute('action', "index.php");

var Category = (function () {
    var categoryCount = 0;

    function elem(tag) { // shortcut
        return document.createElement(tag);
    }

    function text(str) { // shortcut
        return document.createTextNode(str);
    }

    function Category(node) {
        var self = this;
        this.categoryId = ++categoryCount;
        // make add button
        this.addButton = elem('button');
        this.addButton.appendChild(text('Add Textbox'));
        this.addButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            self.addTextbox();
        });
        // make wrapper
        this.wrapper = elem('section');
        this.wrapper.setAttribute('id', 'cat'+this.categoryId);
        this.wrapper.appendChild(this.addButton);
        // make textboxes
        this.textboxes = [];
        this.addTextbox();
        // append to document
        if (node) {
            this.append(node);
        }

    }

    Category.prototype.addTextbox = function () {
        var e = document.createElement("input");
        e.setAttribute('name', 'cat-'+this.categoryId+'-textbox[]');
        f.appendChild(e); // this is where each textbox is supposed to be added to the form...
        this.textboxes.push(e);
        this.wrapper.insertBefore(e, this.addButton);
    };

    Category.prototype.append = function (node) {
        return node.appendChild(this.wrapper);
    };

    return Category;
}());

var s = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
s.setAttribute('type',"submit");
s.setAttribute('value',"Submit");
f.appendChild(s);

//var cat1 = new Category(document.body);
//var cat2 = new Category(document.body);
//document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
```

The above comment is only for you to see what this script is doing and those three lines are not actually in my .js file. the following comments are part of what is in my PHP file, pretty much just outputting the above comments:

```
$counter = 0;
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/categories.js"></script>';

foreach ($catArr as $category) {
    $counter++;
    echo 'do<script>var cat'.$counter.' = new Category(document.body);</script>';
}

echo "<script>document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);</script>";
```

My problem is that with the form I created in the JS, the GET is not delivering any data.  My php page is simply going from index.php to index.php? with the question mark, and not with any of the textbox variables following the question mark.  For some reason, the form is not finding those textboxes that are created or their names.  Please help me out.

Comment: Also, cheating the system with code tags isn't very nice either...

Comment: Additionally, some people are behind firewalls that prevent access to JSFiddle, so without any code at all, they can't offer much help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: You are creating the input elements outside of the form tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
var cat1 = new Category(document.body);
function Category(node) {
        var self = this;
        this.categoryId = ++categoryCount;
        // make add button
        this.addButton = elem('button');
        this.addButton.appendChild(text('Add Textbox'));
        this.addButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            self.addTextbox();
        });
        // make wrapper
        this.wrapper = elem('section');
        this.wrapper.setAttribute('id', 'cat'+this.categoryId);
        this.wrapper.appendChild(this.addButton);
        // make textboxes
        this.textboxes = [];
        this.addTextbox();
        // append to document
        if (node) {
            this.appendChild(node);
        }

    }
```

appends all your input text boxes to the `body` and not the `form`, so when you press Submit no data is being passed

fiddle with working code: http://jsfiddle.net/5H8Pv/1/

Comment: You will also find that the add button will submit your form unless you explicitly set type="button"

Comment: @Joe - I've added this.addButton.setAttribute('type', 'button'); and still the form is submitting upon adding the textbox... hmm

Comment: @Jess this works: http://jsfiddle.net/5H8Pv/1/, I added `f.appendChild(this.wrapper);` in the Category function

Comment: @Jess whats happening now? also does PHP output anything?

Comment: @stackErr: If you look at the fiddle from before, it also appears to work in there for some reason.  So adding that didn't fix anything :(  It is still submitting the data upon trying to add a textbox.  The good thing is that the data is actually displaying in the URL now, which is what I have been trying to do with the GET.  I just need to fix it so that the form data is not submitted when adding the textbox.  It is weird that this problem is not being displayed in the fiddle.  It must have to do with calling in the script from the php file?

Comment: @Jess which browser are you using? On Chrome in my fiddle if I add a text box, it does not submit the form

Comment: @Jess I think you need to ask another question regarding your PHP/JS on SE, as your original question is resolved. Also i would need to see more of your PHP to get a better idea of whats happening